# Is it better for performance not to add fk to tables in the code first approach entity framework core

Tags: performance, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first

there is a topic I was wondering friends. I'm running EntityFrameworkCore code first, and in one article I came across an expression: "If you need virtual jobs, see Include ()." Now, if I remove all the foreign keys in the tables, is the performance better or does it have an effect.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ef core will generate FKs whether you include them or not in your model.

e.g.

example source : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/shadow-properties

```
class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}

public class Blog
{
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }

    public List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}

public class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public Blog Blog { get; set; }
}
```

"For example, the following code listing will result in a BlogId shadow property being introduced to the Post entity."

So in conclusion removing them will have no effect in the performance of your queries

Comment: thanks a lot @mesies, I think the approach I will use when writing the query is more important in this case, I understand correctly. For example, lazy loading, eager loading. From what I understand, it doesn't affect whether or not fk's are there.

Comment: yes you are on the right track, try to think what sql commands will be generated by your linq queries and you will be fine!